# Spring HibernateDaoSupport keep the same Session?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In the standalone application(single threaded command line tool) I am developing ,I use Spring +Hibernate.
It has DAO and Service layers and for DAOs I use HibernateDAOSupport.
The collections in domain model are lazy-loading.

Since for lazy-loading I need to keep the Session opended,I open session at start of my application using:

```
HibernateTemplate tmpl;     
SessionFactoryUtils.initDeferredClose(tmpl.getSessionFactory());

//do file reads,parse CSV , persist objects (normally takes along time)
//
//Finally

SessionFactoryUtils.processDeferredClose(tmpl.getSessionFactory());
```

But during execution ,I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException:
>   Illegal attempt to associate a
>   collection with two open sessions;
>   nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   Illegal attempt to associate a
>   collection with two open sessions
>   Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   Illegal attempt to associate a
>   collection with two open sessions     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:410)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:293)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:223)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:33)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:564)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:552)

How to fix this?

> at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:544)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$14.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:657)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:372)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.update(HibernateTemplate.java:654)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.update(HibernateTemplate.java:650)
>     at
>   com.bigg.nihonbare.common.dao.hibernate.CommonDAOImpl.updateFamily(CommonDAOImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   com.bigg.nihonbare.common.service.impl.CommonServiceImpl.updateFamily(CommonServiceImpl.java:55)
>     at
>   com.bigg.nihonbare.util.flow.DynaRowHibernateUpdateHandler.handleRow(DynaRowHibernateUpdateHandler.java:72)

NOTE : In my DAOs I only have used methods like;

```
return (Long) this.getHibernateTemplate().save(family);

return (Family) this.getHibernateTemplate().execute(
                new HibernateCallback() {
                    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
                        Criteria criteria = session
                                .createCriteria(Family.class);
                        criteria.add(Expression.eq("familyId", familyId));
                        if (criteria.list().size() > 0) {
                            return criteria.list().get(0);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch for `getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession()` in your DAO, you might be ending up opening 2 sessions, since you lately switched to this architecture, I know it from your other previous question.

Hint: Use `getSession()` instead. This [SpringSource Forum's thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=26782) might be helpful.

Comment: thanks Vinegar,but i havent used getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession() in my DAOs,I have only used like:

return (Long) this.getHibernateTemplate().save(family);

and


return (Family) this.getHibernateTemplate().execute(
    new HibernateCallback() {
     public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
      Criteria criteria = session
        .createCriteria(Family.class);
      criteria.add(Expression.eq("familyId", familyId));
      if (criteria.list().size() > 0) {
       return criteria.list().get(0);
      }
      return null;
     }
});

Comment: I suppose using hibernateTemplate to execute or save, tend to open a new session to perform the things. For example, `getHibernateTemplate().save(family)`, will use Session.save() somewhere down the road, and most likely will open a new session. What say you?

Comment: getHibernateTemplate() can open a new session.  see the src code here:  http://bit.ly/HsgDrR  a common practice is to use spring's @Transactional annotation to wrap methods in your dao in a transaction. if you do this, calling anything other than getSession() can cause new sessions to be opened outside your transaction and leak.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of session associated to each thread separately .session is not a 
Shared variables but sessionfactory is，session is created by spring container  if you inject sessionfactory into DAO.